# AJAX call returns html code in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a code which creates table with php (10x10) and each cell has a number from 1-100. 
I am trying to create ajax call which shows number of a cell in textarea. But in textarea there is full html code instead of number.

This is my ajax call:

```
            $('td').click(function () {

            var name_val = parseInt($(this).text());

            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "find.php",
               data: { name: name_val },
               success: function (response){
                   $("textarea#tekst").val(response);
               }
            });

            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            $(this).addClass("ajaxTest");
        });
```

Comment: try a console.log(response) inside your success callback to inspect the returned data

Comment: please show your `find.php`

Comment: So this means that `response` contains that full HTML code. You can do two things: 1, Parse the content in JavaScript or 2 (probably best), modify the PHP code so it only return the number. If you need help with that, you will need to share the PHP code too.

Comment: i just updated my post

Comment: i use session_start() for something else, which works fine

Comment: So what is your objective? `textarea` doesn't render html so it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: in textarea i can see pure code, i mean it's like in notepad. What i want is to show in textarea is number of a cell.

Comment: well i am trying, but i don't know how should i change the ajax call to do that

Comment: what is wrong with php page?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that a `textarea` is for text. Not for "cells" and not for `html` `tables`.

Your php is rendering an `html` `table`, 10 x 10 and the code is shown in the textarea. That's purely the purpose of it: *show text*.

In order to get the numbers only, change the `textarea` to `<div>  </div` container.

Comment: it shows nothing at all.
but i would still like to show cell number in textarea with ajax. 
there is realy no way to do that?

Comment: nope. Forgot: you need to change your `...a#tekst").val(response);` to `...a#tekst").html(response);`